# Jasmine async testing without settimeout

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm looking to create some jasmine specs for a piece of code that has async functionality.

In the jasmine docs it shows the example:

```
it("takes a long time", function(done) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            done();
          }, 9000);
        });
```

Using the done function and a setTimeout, my issue with this is setTimout could be fragile i.e. delays in test runs in enviros

is there an alternative solution to such tests where I don't have to use a timeout?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how you calculate result of async function - by callback, promise or await?

Comment: Take a look at [jasmine-co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-co). With this npm package you can use `yield` and drop `setTimeout()` and `done()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example `setTimeout` is actually the function being tested. It's used as a representative example of an asynchronous function. The key point is that you must explicitly call `done()` when your test is complete. Your code should look something like:

`it("takes a long time", function(done) {
  myMethod('foo', 'bar', function callback() {
    assert(...)
    done();
  }); // callback-style
}`

`it("takes a long time", function(done) {
   myMethod('foo', 'bar').then(function() {
    assert(...)
    done();
   }); // promise-style
});`

`it("takes a long time", async function(done) {
   await myMethod('foo', 'bar')
   assert(...)
   done()
});`

Answer (score 0):

The documented function is intended to illustrate using the `done` callback following a long-running method, and should not be used for actual tests.

Normally, you would expect a long running function to be supplied with a callback in which you would call the `done` function.  For example, you could write a unit test involving a file that took a long time to write data:

```
it("writes a lot of data", function(done) {
  var fd = 999; // Obtain a file descriptor in some way...

  fs.write(fd, veryLongString, function (err, written, string) {
    // Carry out verification here, after the file has been written
    done();
  });
```

Again, this is only illustrative, as you would generally not want to write to a file within the body of a unit test.  But the idea is that you can call `done` after some long-running operation.